# How to Restrict Drag and Drop for UIWebView for particular elements?

Tags: uiwebview, drag-and-drop, ios11

I have webview with the topics loaded in it. It contains links,Images,Videos etc. Is it possible to restrict drag and drop for Images and Videos?